# Bandsintown Api parsing json with php

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

I'm trying to parse a Json response from the bandsintown api, but I'm getting stucked with a "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

My code is as it follows:

```
<?php
        //Get the list of events from the function
        $events = GetJsonFeed("http://api.bandsintown.com/example");

        //Loop through
        foreach ($events as $event) 
        { 
            echo "<h3> $event->title </h3>"; //title
            echo "<p> $event->formatted_datetime </p>";
            echo "<p> $event->venue->latitude </p>";
            echo "<p> $event->venue->longitude </p>";
            echo "<a href='$event->facebook_rsvp_url'>RSVP</a>"; //RSVP link
            echo "</div>";

        }

    ?>
```

The json response is something like this:

```
[{"artists":[{.....}],

"formatted_datetime":"Saturday, March 9, 2013 at 9:00pm",

"ticket_type":null,

"ticket_status":"unavailable",

"description":null,

"venue":{"latitude":"38.7166667","region":"14","longitude":"-9.1333333"},

"ticket_url":null}]
```

I'm only getting the error when I try to echo the latitude and longitude.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some of your variables are not strings, try `var_dump($event)`

Comment: json_decoded($events,true)...........post the output